# How to set list on sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-addin

I have attached 2 pictures:
1: List view That should Display (Left Corner)
2: List that displayed (Wrong one) right corner

I don't know why it is appearing on right lane. i want to display it on left side as well as well formatted.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have the same list displayed with the Classic UI first and the Modern UI second. The Class UI looks like it has a custom InfoPath form, which is not supported in the Modern UI.

In the bottom left corner of your Modern UI screen capture is a the link "Return to Classic SharePoint". Click that to return to the Classic UI.

Answer (score 1):

Just like Mike said, it seems you want to only use classic UI for that list.

You can change the default settings for that list. Check this:
[Switch the default experience for lists or document libraries from new or classic](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/switch-the-default-experience-for-lists-or-document-libraries-from-new-or-classic-66dac24b-4177-4775-bf50-3d267318caa9?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)